# How to use only part of a monitor to display the entire desktop?

Tags: windows-10, hdmi, external-display

I use a 32-inch [monitor](https://www.samsung.com/hk_en/monitors/flat/led-monitor-32-inch-ls32f351fucxxk/) which is excellent for browsing and multimedia. However, I’d like to be closer to the monitor when studying. This problem is because the monitor is too big and strains my neck.

Can you only use part of the monitor (say, the bottom left quarter) to display everything? As the monitor continuously pumps up low-resolution input, I want the computer to continue sending a Full-HD signal while rendering the entire desktop in the lower left quarter only (or similar size/position), leaving the rest in black (see picture).

I’m on Windows 10 with an Intel HD 620 GPU. The following figure shows what I’m seeking:

[image: huge monitor showing a Windows 10 desktop in the lower left quarter of the screen and black everywhere else. The entire desktop (including background, task bar, full-screen app etc.) covers only a corner of the screen.]

Some smartphones have a similar accessibility function (“one-handed mode”) as show here exemplary:

[image: smartphone where the entire screen contented is resized to 70% and moved to the lower left corner, making it easier to interact with everything with the left hand holding the phone]

Comment: Fiebbo, this is going to be a function of the screen probably more than of the software. Windows lets you adjust the resolution it sends, but most LCD screens automatically scale the display up to full-screen regardless of the resolution of the input signal. Also, Windows supports "windows" for pretty much this exact purpose. Part of the counsel here on SU is to keep an open mind. Simply using a black background and not maximizing your application will accomplish perhaps 75% of what you're looking for without any extra work. Though Adelaide's grid manager may be worth checking out too.

Comment: On Linux, this [is possible.](https://superuser.com/a/1780351/119621)

Answer (score 2):

After setting the background to black, you can use the built-in window snapping - drag a window to a corner of the screen and it should resize to fit 1/4 of the screen.

Alternately there are window grid managers that you could investigate:

http://www.online-tech-tips.com/free-software-downloads/split-or-divide-your-desktop-screen-into-multiple-parts/

Comment: This really isn't an answer to OPs question. It may be as close as we can get, but it is rather clear OP was trying to limit the entire OS UI to a specific subsection of the display.