# Is there a way for windows 11 not to use say top 10% of the screen or 10% left of the screen?

Tags: windows-10

I have a projector that is a bit unfocused on the top left corner.

It's okay. But I wonder if I don't have to use the left and top edge of the screen.

I wonder if there's an app for that?

I mean the projector is 4k. Losing a bit pixels on the edges is fine anyway

Comment: Adjust the width and height **in the projector** See https://superuser.com/questions/1188800/how-to-use-only-part-of-a-monitor-to-display-the-entire-desktop